# Are there any examples of iOS apps written using PyObjC?

Tags: python, ios, pyobjc

The only references I can find state that it's theoretically possible to write iOS apps using python. Does anyone know of any examples of apps that were written this way?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the iOS PyObjC hasn't really been maintained:

[Python Hello World in PyObjC on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999366/python-hello-world-in-pyobjc-on-iphone)

Comment: why was this downvoted? Seems at least relevant.

Answer (score 1):

This is the best project I have ever seen related with the topic

http://pyzia.com

Unfortunatelly, you can't download it yet.

Without it, I think you're left with [PyObjC](http://pythonhosted.org/pyobjc/).

You have a good introductory tutorial [here](http://lethain.com/an-epic-introduction-to-pyobjc-and-cocoa/).